# How can I get my program to just count a word that is by itself while using a do-while loop?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program that finds a 'profane' word (which is 'cat' in this case) and say how many times it comes up in my input, and it works, except that it will count that profane word when it is embedded in a another word like 'conCATination'. Why is this the case? How can I get it to just count it when the word is by itself?
*Edit: I forgot to mention it has to be done using if-else statements as well as using a loop* Here is my program so far:

```
    private static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sentence = "";
        String word1 = "cat";
        int indexofSW1 = 0;
        int currentlocation = 0;
        int sentenceLength = 0;
        int word1Count = 0;
        int word1Length;
        System.out.println("Please enter a sentence.");
        sentence = keyboard.nextLine().toLowerCase().trim();
        word1Length = word1.length();
        indexofSW1 = sentence.indexOf(word1 , indexofSW1);
        sentenceLength = sentence.length();
        char character1;
if (indexofSW1 >= 0)
            do { if (sentenceLength > indexofSW1 + word1Length) 
            {
                character1 = sentence.charAt(indexofSW1 + word1Length);
                switch (character1) {
                case ' ':
                case '\'':
                case '\t':
                case '\"':
                case '.':
                case '?':
                case '<':
                case '>':
                case ',':
                case '[':
                case ']':
                case '{':
                case '}':
                case '(':
                case ')':
                case '-':
                case '_':
                case '\\':
                case '|':
                case '+':
                case '=':
                case '/':
                case '*':
                case '&':
                case '^':
                case '%':
                case '$':
                case '#':
                case '@':
                case '!':

    }
                 currentlocation = sentence.indexOf(word1, currentlocation);
                }

             if (currentlocation == 0 || currentlocation > 0)
             {  
                    currentlocation += word1Length;
                    word1Count++;
            }
}while(currentlocation > -1 && currentlocation > sentenceLength);

 System.out.printf("You have profane word %s %d times in your sentence." , word1 , word1Count);}}
```

Comment: `String word1 = " cat ";`

Comment: *Why is this the case?* Why wouldn't it be? *How can I get it to just count it when the word is by itself?* Check what's before and after.

Comment: Before you create such a huge *switch statement* consider using **regex matching**.

Comment: @Wright What about `cat` word at the beginning or at the end of sentence?

Comment: This would be more appropriatly solved via RegEx matches, is this homework?

Comment: It is homework, and I am just a beginner, I tried to post to the homework tag, but it wouldn't let me. It has to be done exactly this way, and I tried several things already to have it check what comes before and after, but nothing seemed to work. Should the check come before the do-while loop, or be done inside of it?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using regex in this example, as it seems to be much better choice:

```
String source = "cat at the beginning, in the middle cat too, concatenating at the end cat.";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\b)+(cat)(?=\\b)+");    // "cat" preceded by one or more whitespace characters or word boundary and followed by this too.
Matcher m = p.matcher(source);     // Set matcher to match given pattern
int counter = 0;    // to count occurences of "cat" int given String
while(m.find()) {    // if match was found...
    counter++;    // increment counter
    System.out.println(m.group(1) + " beginning from index: " + m.start(1)); // print match to the console
}
System.out.println("Number of occurences: " + counter);    // print number of occurences of "cat"
```

Output that you get from this code:

```
cat beginning from index: 0
cat beginning from index: 36
cat beginning from index: 70
Number of occurences: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use pattern.matcher with regex

```
   String cat = "cat concatination cat cat. cat";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("cat | cat");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(cat);

        int count = 0;
        while (matcher.find())
            count++;

        System.out.println(count);    // prints 3
```

Comment: What about the `cat` at the very beginning of the string?

Comment: @Przemysław Moskal  , thank you, i updated my response

Comment: It failes with word `concat` now.